# replicating Access query into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a MS Access Query that I am trying to convert into SQL Server, as I prefer this platform and find it more functional.  I have an issue where Access will ask you for a number based on the day of the week because the query is looking back.  I have added that functionality into SQL Server (and a bit more based on our needs) but I am facing an issue where sometimes the results might be a few days off. I can get the same results in Access but I have to change the number I am inputting for the day variable.  Both codes are below.

Thank you,

SQL SERVER CODE:

```
DECLARE @daynumber as int
SET     @daynumber = CASE
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Monday'
                  THEN 56
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Tuesday' 
                  THEN 57
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Wednesday' 
                  THEN 58
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Thursday' 
                  THEN 59
                  WHEN DATENAME(dw,GETDATE()) = 'Friday' 
                  THEN 60
                  END;


SELECT          P1.PLANT_CODE,
                P1.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P1.PERIOD_CODE,
                P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P1.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P1.PLANNED_QTY,
                P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P1.[REM_PLAN],
                P2.FUTURE_FCST,
                SUM(I1.ON_HAND_QUANTITY) AS 'TOTAL_OH_INV'
FROM


(SELECT         P.PLANT_CODE,
                P.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P.PERIOD_CODE,
                P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P.PLANNED_QTY,
                P.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.PLANNED_QTY - P.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY AS 'REM_PLAN'
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.PLANT_CODE IN ('6040','6041')
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 AND            P.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE IN ('00','01','ZU','Z2')
 AND            P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE < GETDATE() - @daynumber
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY > 0) AS P1

 LEFT OUTER JOIN      

 (SELECT
                SUM(P.PLANNED_QTY) AS 'FUTURE_FCST',
                P.MATERIAL,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX
 FROM           VW_PLANNED_REQMNTS_TXT P
 WHERE          P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE > GETDATE()
 AND            P.PLANNED_QTY > 0
 AND            P.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
 GROUP BY       P.MATERIAL,
                P.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P.SIZE_LITERAL) AS P2
 ON             P1.MATERIAL = P2.MATERIAL
 AND            P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = P2.TECHNICAL_INDEX

 LEFT OUTER JOIN 

 (SELECT        I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                I.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                I.MATERIAL,
                I.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                I.PLANT_CODE
  FROM          VW_INVENTORY I
  WHERE         I.STOCK_CATEGORY IN ('A60385000','A60385003')
  GROUP BY      I.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                I.MATERIAL,
                I.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                I.ON_HAND_QUANTITY,
                I.PLANT_CODE) AS I1

  ON            P1.MATERIAL = I1.MATERIAL
  AND           P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX = I1.TECHNICAL_INDEX
  AND           P1.PLANT_CODE = I1.PLANT_CODE

  GROUP BY      P1.PLANT_CODE,
                P1.STOCK_CATEGORY,
                P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.DISTRIBUTION_VERSION_CODE,
                P1.PERIOD_CODE,
                P1.REQUIREMENTS_DATE,
                P1.PLANNED_QTY,
                P1.VERSION_IND_FLAG,
                P1.WITHDRAWN_QUANTITY,
                P1.SIZE_LITERAL,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX,
                P1.[REM_PLAN],
                P2.FUTURE_FCST


 ORDER BY       P1.MATERIAL,
                P1.TECHNICAL_INDEX;
```

ACCESS CODE:

```
SELECT dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.plant_code,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.stock_category,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.material,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.distribution_version_code,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.period_code,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.requirements_date,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.planned_qty   AS [REM PLAN QTY],
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.version_ind_flag,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.size_literal,
       dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.withdrawn_quantity,
       ( [planned_qty] + [withdrawn_quantity] ) AS [Original Fcst Qty]
FROM   dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt
GROUP  BY dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.plant_code,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.stock_category,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.material,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.distribution_version_code,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.period_code,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.requirements_date,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.planned_qty,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.version_ind_flag,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.size_literal,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.withdrawn_quantity,
          ( [planned_qty] + [withdrawn_quantity] ),
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.technical_index
HAVING ( ( ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.plant_code ) = "6040"
            OR ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.plant_code ) = "6041" )
         AND ( ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.stock_category ) = "a60385000"
                OR ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.stock_category ) = "a60385003" )
         AND ( ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.distribution_version_code ) = "00"
                OR
         ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.distribution_version_code ) = "01"
                OR
         ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.distribution_version_code ) = "zu"
                OR
         ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.distribution_version_code ) = "z2" )
         AND ( ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.requirements_date ) < Now()
                   - [m: 56 t:57 w:58 th: 59 f:60] )
         AND ( ( dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.planned_qty ) > 0 ) )
ORDER  BY dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.plant_code,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.stock_category,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.material,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.requirements_date,
          dbo_vw_planned_reqmnts_txt.technical_index;
```

Comment: I doubt this will fix your issue, but I prefer to set GetDate() into a variable at the start and refer to the variable throughout my SQL. That way I can guarantee that I'm not getting strange results due to the value of GetDate() changing by a few millseconds while the SQL is executing.

Comment: that actually might be a good point.  I wrote the SQL Server code based of their Access code, I don't even now if GETDATE() is a valid command in Access... but you bring up a good point

Comment: It's not a valid command in Access.

Comment: Two questions.  (1) In SQLServer is P.REQUIREMENTS_DATE defined as date or datetime?  (2) Are you absolutely sure there are no '@daynumber' that fall on Saturday or Sunday (even by seconds due to time zone) thus causing '@daynumber' to be zero?